# Module Dependency in Intellij- not able to reference Classes from other Projects

Tags: spring, gradle, intellij-idea, module, dependencies

I need to use a java class from project A in Project B. I believe I wrote the package and import successfully but I still get a message when compiling (`./gradlew` clean build) saying:

```
java:3: `error: package x.x.x.x.x.common.api.filter does not exist`
```

Next, I tried to create a module dependency within `IntelliJ`, by importing the new package as a Module and rewriting the package and import statement to reflect the imported package (module dependency) but I am still seeing the same error.

```
java:3: error: package x.x.x.x.x.common.api.filter does not exist
```

Would this be an issue with the `build.gradle` file? Or my setting up of the module dependency?
How can I resolve?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `build.gradle` configuration and is not related to the IDE.

You should define the dependencies between the projects as described in [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies).

Another possible solution is [Composite Builds](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/webinar-recording-composite-builds-with-gradle/).